# Filter array where column value exists in a Dataverse table column

Tags: arrays, power-automate

I have an array of thousands of rows with an element of "Order Number." I want to filter that array where that Order Number does not exist in a Dataverse table column.

I've tried a number of things, always starting with a List Rows action on the Dataverse table. From there, I feel like the thing to do is to do a Select action where I map OrderNumber to OrderNumber from the List Rows. I believe that creates an array of the order numbers.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but how can I efficiently filter the original array where the Order Number does not exist in the Dataverse table?

Edit: Here's a sample item in the output of my current filter array:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: How should I show the data?

Comment: That should be fine, just so other users can see the structure to help you out. I've never worked with Dataverse tables before but usually this type of filter will happen at the point you request data from the server. It would also be helpful to show your data request code. How do you request data from the server?

Comment: It's pretty complicated, actually. It involves processing a CSV file. I also don't think it really matters though. I just need to filter the array again in Power Automate.

Comment: I could probably tell you how to process the raw data in javascript to eliminate matching records if that would help

Comment: In Power Automate?

Comment: You would have to check if you can use javascript with your program

Comment: This ... "I want to filter that array where that Order Number does not exist in a Dataverse table column" ... do you mean where it doesn't exist in **ANY** column or the **OrderNumber** column?  You make it sound like you're talking about any column.

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you are able to use javascript.

```
// where output equals your data
const records = JSON.parse( output );

// we will create new array of filtered data
let newData = [];

// loop array searching for matching criteria
for (let n = 0; n < records.length; n++; ) {

   // replace 123456 with search criteria
   if(records[n]["Order Number"] != "123456") {
         newData.push(records[n]);
   }

   // once you reach the end
   if(n == records.length-1) {
      
      // stringify object (may not be required)
      let fileteredData = JSON.stringify(newData);

      /* open filteredData with program */
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can do that in Power Automate. I can't find an action to run JavaScript.